Reference regarding quotients of link groups induced by link inclusions
Let $\mathcal L=K_1\cup K_2\cup\cdots\cup K_n$ be a link whose connected components are the knots $K_i$. Denote also $\mathcal L_i:=\mathcal L\backslash K_i$. The link group of $\mathcal L$ is $\pi_\mathcal L:=\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\backslash \mathcal L)$.
It is a classical result that $\pi_\mathcal L$ is generated by the meridians of $\mathcal L$.
A result which I expect to be very standard is that $\pi_{\mathcal L_i}$ is the quotient of $\pi_\mathcal L$ by the (normal closure of) the meridians of $K_i$. For example, this result follows from comparing the corresponding Wirtinger presentations.
However, I could not locate a precise reference which does it. In particular, I did not find it in Rolfsen's book. What would be the standard reference for this result ?

You can use Seifert–Van Kampen theorem.

Maybe I was not clear: I am not looking for a proof but rather for the first paper/book where this result (about the quotients of link groups) is stated, if it exists. Thank you for your comment though !


When you add in the relator that sets a given meridian $=$ identity in the group (which has the effect of taking the quotient by the normal subgroup corresponding to that relator), this is the same as performing Dehn filling on the manifold, adding a solid torus such that its meridian goes to the meridian of the component in question. The resulting manifold is the link complement with one fewer crossing.

You're quite right to say that $\pi_{L_i}$ is the quotient of $\pi_L$ by the (normal closure of) the meridians of $K_i$ (though you only need one meridian). It's a consequence of Van Kampen's theorem, which discusses what happens to the fundamental group when two spaces are glued together. In particular, for a cell complex (like a simplicial complex only using balls instead of simplexes) if you glue on a cell by its boundary, for a $1$-cell you get a new generator, for a $2$-cell you get a new (obvious?) relator and the higher dimension cells make no difference at all. Take out an open solid torus neighborhood of $K_i$. A solid torus has its boundary, the torus, to which is glued a disk (a $2$-cell) and a $3$-cell. Only the disk is of interest and that adds a relation to $\pi_L$ as you have discovered.


